# Javascript: Filtering array items for the first letter and then for the others

Tags: javascript

I have an array of cities and using a search input I'm filtering it per name of the city. For example if I type "b" I see Barcelona, Berlin, Bucharest, and Budapest, but also Dublin and Lisbon (because they contain the letter "b".)

I'm looking for a way to filter FIRST for the the first letter I type and then for the others letters. For instance, if I type "b" I should see only Barcelona, Berlin, Bucharest, and Budapest. If I type "bu", it should now show Budapest and Bucharest. How can I obtain this result?

Here my actual piece of code:

```
{this.props.cities
.filter(city => city.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchTerm) !== -1)
.map(item => ( <p> {item.name} </p> ))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of testing whether `indexOf()` returns something other than `-1`, test if it returns exactly `0`. That means it matches at the beginning of the city name.

```
this.props.cities
.filter(city => city.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchTerm) === 0)
.map(item => ( <p> {item.name} </p> ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith), and for added accuracy, apply both [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) and [String.prototype.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to `searchTerm` and `city.name`.

See the simplified example below:

```js
const cities = ['Barcelona', 'Berlin', 'Bucharest', 'Budapest', 'Dublin', 'Lisbon'];
const searchTerm = 'b';

const filteredCities = cities.filter(city => city.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(searchTerm.trim().toLowerCase()));

console.log(filteredCities);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{this.props.cities
.filter(city => city.name.toLowerCase().substring(0,searchVal.length) === searchVal.toLowerCase())
.map(item => ( <p> {item.name} </p> ))}
```

Something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **startsWith** method [compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_string_startswith).

Depending of where you want to run this piece of code, you can use the following snippet

```js
{this.props.cities
.filter(city => city.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.state.searchTerm))
.map(item => ( <p> {item.name} </p> ))}
```